# How to recover configure command line arguments used before?

Tags: makefile, arguments, configure, recover

I have ran configure on a software project a long time ago and have forgotten which command line arguments I had used at the time. Since then the configure script changed and, so now I want to rerun configure with the same arguments to update the Makefile.

I have the old Makefile and configure script as well as the old sources. The history file for my CLI doesn't have it anymore.

How can I recover which command line arguments were used when I originally ran configure?

Comment: If you have the `config.log` or `config.status` files from the previous run, you can find the arguments there.  If you don't have any output generated by the previous run, then clearly there's no way to recover whatever arguments you used before, since that was all deleted.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you very much. If you make an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: Does your project use Automake in addition to Autoconf?  If so, then you might not need to do anything other than re-run `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the arguments used by your last `configure` call in `config.log` and `config.status`.